# garbage value stored in temporary pointer

Tags: c, pointers, scanf, garbage

```
int *intp
int *temp    
FILE *fp = fopen("a.txt", "r");

temp = intp = (int *)malloc(intcnt * sizeof(int));

while (fscanf(fp, "%d", temp++) != EOF)
    ;
```

** intcnt will be given as an argument to this function

Debugging tools in VS shows that the value of
*intp is integer numbers in "a.txt" which is the result I was expecting, not a problem.
But the value of *temp is different.
It seems to be a garbage value.
I thought the the value of two expression should be the same because one's address was allocated to the other's address.
What brings such difference?

Comment: `temp++`.......`temp` pointed to uninitialized value at loop end.

Comment: `temp` has changed in the while loop. It probably now points just past the end of the array, or perhaps a bit before it or far after it, depending on how accurate `intcnt` was for the number of integers read.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I checked its value throughout the loop and the value was garbage regardless of iteration

Comment: You should _always_ check the result of `fopen()` to be certain that the file opened successfully.

Comment: @장동욱 If you checked in the loop, it is pointless. Because `temp` point to uninitialized value after `temp++`.

Comment: Try replacing `while (fscanf(fp, "%d", temp++) != EOF)` with `if(!fp || !temp) { fputs("ERROR\n", stderr); } else { while (temp - intp < intcnt && fscanf(fp, "%d", temp++) == 1); }`. It would be easier to help if you post a [mcve], though